# can we get the boolean value(true or false) whether the deleted tr was last or not inside the div?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="parent_${id}"></div>

var tableHead = "<table id='ftTableID'><thead><th class='th4'>First Name</th><th class='th5'>Last Name</th><th>Action</th></thead>")}"+"";  

$('#parent_itemId').prepend(tableHead);
$('#ftTableID').append("</table>");
```

After this appending the new `tr` to the `div`:

```
var $newElem = $("<tr>").html(elem).attr({'id': id + num1, 'no': num1});

// creates the "Remove" button
var $removeButton = $('<input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="Delete" /></tr>').appendTo($newElem);

$removeButton.attr({
    id: 'remove_' + id,
    value: removeBtnLabel ? removeBtnLabel : 'Remove',
    disabled: 'disabled'
});

// binds handler to the 'click' JS event of the "Remove" button
$removeButton.click(function () {
    removeItem(id, num1, min);
});
```

appending the `tr` to the `div`:

```
$('#parent_' + id).append($newElem);
```

First `tr` will be appended in the above `div id` with  *ADD* and *CANCEL* button beside it.  While we click *ADD* button, next `tr` will be added with *ADD* and *CANCEL* Button beside it.  *ADD* button will be omitted from the first `tr` leaving only *CANCEL* button in the first `tr` and so on.  Now when I press the *CANCEL* button I need to get whether the deleted row(`tr`) was the last row or not?

Now when the removeItem() function is called I want to find whether the `tr` is last `tr` or not?

Comment: `$('tr:last')` try this the selector `:last` or method `.last()`

Comment: Does each `tr` have it's own cancel button which will delete that `tr`?

Comment: yes each tr  have its own cancel button that deletes respective tr @wmash

Comment: Can you please post your HTML so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html after adding two rows dynamically:

```
<div id="parent_${id}">
     <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="CancelBtn1" />
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Add2" />
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="CancelBtn2"/>
               </td>
          </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

You can use the below code on Cancel button click:

```
if($(this).closest("tr").next().is("tr"))
{

//it is not the last row
}
else
{
 //it is the last row
}
```

Comment: i am appending the tr in the div not in the table .. not working ..THANKS for your time anyways.

Comment: Adding tr without table is not the correct HTML syntax. Is there any specific reason for same ?

Comment: i am trying to create a dynamic horizontal form. In this case if i add a table then the table head will also be added in the next tr. so i have made the table head leaving the body blank and appendend in the div.and  i have appended the tr separately.

Comment: You can add the table tag only once using a flag, therefore, it won't be added in the next tr. If it does not help then share the dynamic html along with code.